# "I tend to make it about me" - What does this phrase mean?

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

> I know I tend to make it about me
>   I know you never get just what you see
>   But I will never bore you, ba-a-by
>   And there's a lot of lame guys out there
>   And when we had that fight out in the rain
>   You ran after me and called my name
>   I never want to see you walk away
>   And there's a lot of lame guys out there

"I know I tend to make it about me" - What does it mean?

Comment: Why did you include `indian-english` and `non-standard-english`? It's an American song...

Answer (score 6):

To "make something about oneself" means to view a situation entirely from one's own point of view, ignoring or minimising any impact or involvement of other people. It is generally thought of as selfish behaviour.

> **Example:**
>   Person1: "I looked dreadful at John's funeral. It was raining, I got soaking wet and I just felt a mess".
>
> Person2: "Wow, you've really made it about yourself".

"*I tend to make it about me/myself*" is an acknowledgement that they make a habit of, or have a tendency to do this.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry to say, I've one more doubt to ask you. The second line is " I know you never get just what you see". In this phrase, what the meaning of 'get'. Does it mean 'to understand ' or 'to obtain'.

Comment: @AashiqSoy it's a line from the lyrics of "Me" by Taylor Swift and it's open to different interpretations. After watching the video, I guess he can't promise her everything but he won't bore her either. He seems to love her, even though he appears to be too self-centered and full of vanity.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I know. But I wanna know what is the exact meaning of 'get' in the line "I know you never get what you see". What does the word 'get' stand for here. Does it mean 'understanding' or 'obtaining'. I am kinda confused here. Because sometimes the word 'get' is used to refer to 'understanding '.

Comment: @AashiqSoy The thing is you won't figure out the "exact meaning" unless you ask the author.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I think it's the same meaning of "get" as in the Rolling Stones song "You Can't Always Get What You Want". It means to receive or achieve something.

Comment: It seems to me to be nodding towards WYSIWYG: "what you see is what you get". Asking for precise meanings of poems or song lyrics is pointless. There are often many possible answers.

Comment: There's an expression `what you see is what you get` which means that a person is completely honest and transparent with their words.  When you say that you don't get what you see, it means that the person is being misleading.